# Change values in pandas dataframe based on values in certain columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert this first dataframe to the one below it? Based on different scenarios of the first three columns matching, I want to change the values in the rest of the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                   ['spa', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])

  col1 col2 col3 s1 s2 s3 s4
0  foo  foo  bar  a  b  c  d
1  bar  foo  bar  a  b  c  d
2  spa  foo  bar  a  b  c  d
```

If col1 = col2, I want to change all a's to 2, all b's and c's to 1, and all d's to 0. This is row 1 in my example df.

If col1 = col3, I want to change all a's to 0, all b's and c's to 1, and all d's to 2. This is row 2 in my example df.

If col1 != col2/col3, I want to delete the row and add 1 to a counter so I have a total of deleted rows. This is row 3 in my example df.

So my final dataframe would look like this, with counter = 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 'foo', 'bar', '2', '1', '1', '0'], ['bar', 'foo', 'bar', '0', '1', '1', '2']], 
                   columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])

  col1 col2 col3 s1 s2 s3 s4
0  foo  foo  bar  2  1  1  0
1  bar  foo  bar  0  1  1  2
```

I was reading that using df.iterrows is slow and so there must be a way to do this on the whole df at once, but my original idea was:

```
for row in df.iterrows:
    if (row["col1"] == row["col2"]):
        df.replace(to_replace=['a'], value='2', inplace=True)
        df.replace(to_replace=['b', 'c'], value='1', inplace=True)
        df.replace(to_replace=['d'], value='0', inplace=True)
    elif (row["col1"] == row["col3"]):
        df.replace(to_replace=['a'], value='0', inplace=True)
        df.replace(to_replace=['b', 'c'], value='1', inplace=True)
        df.replace(to_replace=['d'], value='2', inplace=True)
    else:
        (delete row, add 1 to counter)
```

The original df is massive, so speed is important to me. I'm hoping it's possible to do the conversions on the whole dataframe without iterrows. Even if it's not possible, I could use help getting the syntax right for the iterrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first:

```
m1 = df["col1"] == df["col2"]
m2 = df["col1"] == df["col3"]
m = m1 | m2
```

Get number of removed rows by `sum` of chained condition `m1` and `m2` with inverting by `~`:

```
counter = (~m).sum()
print (counter)
1
df = df[m].copy()
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 s1 s2 s3 s4
0  foo  foo  bar  a  b  c  d
1  bar  foo  bar  a  b  c  d
```

and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `dictionary` by condition:

```
d1 = {'a':2,'b':1,'c':1,'d':0}
d2 = {'a':0,'b':1,'c':1,'d':2}

m1 = df["col1"] == df["col2"]
#replace all columns without col1-col3
cols = df.columns.difference(['col1','col2','col3'])
df.loc[m1, cols] = df.loc[m1, cols].replace(d1)
df.loc[~m1, cols] = df.loc[~m1, cols].replace(d2)
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 s1 s2 s3 s4
0  foo  foo  bar  2  1  1  0
1  bar  foo  bar  0  1  1  2
```

**Timings**:

```
In [138]: %timeit (jez(df))
872 ms ± 6.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [139]: %timeit (hb(df))
1.33 s ± 9.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Setup**:

```
np.random.seed(456) 

a = ['foo','bar', 'spa']
b = list('abcd')

N = 100000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(a, size=(N, 3))).rename(columns=lambda x: 'col{}'.format(x+1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(b, size=(N, 20))).rename(columns=lambda x: 's{}'.format(x+1))
df = df1.join(df2)
#print (df.head())
```

---

```
def jez(df):
    m1 = df["col1"] == df["col2"]
    m2 = df["col1"] == df["col3"]
    m = m1 | m2
    counter = (~m).sum()
    df = df[m].copy()

    d1 = {'a':2,'b':1,'c':1,'d':0}
    d2 = {'a':0,'b':1,'c':1,'d':2}

    m1 = df["col1"] == df["col2"]
    cols = df.columns.difference(['col1','col2','col3'])
    df.loc[m1, cols] = df.loc[m1, cols].replace(d1)
    df.loc[~m1, cols] = df.loc[~m1, cols].replace(d2)
    return df
```

---

```
def hb(df):
    counter = 0
    df[df.col1 == df.col2] = df[df.col1 == df.col2].replace(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [2,1,1,0])
    df[df.col1 == df.col3] = df[df.col1 == df.col3].replace(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [0,1,1,2])
    index_drop =df[((df.col1 != df.col3) & (df.col1 != df.col2))].index
    counter = counter + len(index_drop)
    df = df.drop(index_drop)
    return df
```

Comment: Could you explain your "df1 = " line a little further? My full dataset has thousands more rows and columns, I can't define "[2,1,1,0], [0,1,1,2]" like you did here. I was looking for something that could directly substitute any 'a' in a row for the correct number based on the col1 = col2, etc conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
               ['spa', 'foo', 'bar', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])
counter = 0

#
df[df.col1 == df.col2] = df[df.col1 == df.col2].replace(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [2,1,1,0])
df[df.col1 == df.col3] = df[df.col1 == df.col3].replace(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [0,1,1,2])
index_drop =df[((df.col1 != df.col3) & (df.col1 != df.col2))].index
counter = counter + len(index_drop)
df = df.drop(index_drop)

print(df)
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    s1  s2  s3  s4
0   foo     foo      bar    2   1   1   0
1   bar     foo      bar    0   1   1   2

1  # counter
```